# ASP.NET Core 3.1: authentication through Active Directory on linux

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, debian

Our application has JWT-base authentication mechanism. I have to add an AD authentication to it but I don't know how to do it. Our application is:

- Backend based on ASP.NET Core 3.1.
- Frontend based on Vue.
- Backend works on Debian but that machine is not an AD domain member. But if it's necessary I can join that machine to domain.

I can't find any information about this question. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) page contains almost no useful information. All other examples are too old and are not actual for 3.1.

For test purpose i've done these steps:

- I've created Samba-based AD domain. Controller and member works on Debian 10:

  - Controller's name is `dc1.mydomain.net`.
  - Domain: `MYDOMAIN`.
  - Realm: `MYDOMAIN.NET`.
  - AD member's name is `m1.mydomain.net`.
- I've set an environment variable `KRB5_KTNAME` with path to keytab file:

  - `export KRB5_KTNAME=$HOME/krb5.keytab`. Previously I've copied krb5.keytab from /etc to ~ and set reading rights for me.
- I've added this code to Startup.cs:

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // ...
            };
        })
        .AddNegotiate(options =>
        {
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                options.EnableLdap(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Domain = "mydomain.net";
                    settings.MachineAccountName = "administrator";
                    settings.MachineAccountPassword = "...";
                });
            }
        });
    
    // …
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

And my questions are:

1. What I have to do now? How to authenticate the user? I can't find any example or instruction.
2. What means `MachineAccountName` and `MachineAccountPassword`? Are it login and password of domain user? Are it necessary? If I use these parameters, I get an exception: "`System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: Strong authentication is required for this operation`".
3. Is it necessary to add some another SPNs to keytab file? Now my keytab file has records:

```
    1 2 host/debian.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    2 2 host/DEBIAN@MYDOMAIN.NET
    3 2 host/debian.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    4 2 host/DEBIAN@MYDOMAIN.NET
    5 2 host/debian.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    6 2 host/DEBIAN@MYDOMAIN.NET
    7 2 host/debian.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    8 2 host/DEBIAN@MYDOMAIN.NET
    9 2 host/debian.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    10 2 host/DEBIAN@MYDOMAIN.NET
    11 2 DEBIAN$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    12 2 DEBIAN$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    13 2 DEBIAN$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    14 2 DEBIAN$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    15 2 DEBIAN$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    16 2 host/m1.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    17 2 host/M1@MYDOMAIN.NET
    18 2 host/m1.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    19 2 host/M1@MYDOMAIN.NET
    20 2 host/m1.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    21 2 host/M1@MYDOMAIN.NET
    22 2 host/m1.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    23 2 host/M1@MYDOMAIN.NET
    24 2 host/m1.mydomain.net@MYDOMAIN.NET
    25 2 host/M1@MYDOMAIN.NET
    26 2 M1$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    27 2 M1$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    28 2 M1$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    29 2 M1$@MYDOMAIN.NET
    30 2 M1$@MYDOMAIN.NET
```

Thanks very much for your answers!

Comment: If you have the option to go "AzureAD", i highly recommend it.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to work with in-corporative AD.